# How can I mix static and dynamic items in Telerik's RadMenu for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I'm using Telerik's controls for Silverlight and I'm trying to get my data bound items to append to the end of my statically defined ones.  I'm using the following code right now:

```
telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Tag Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.TagCategories}" 
                            DisplayMemberPath="Code" >
<telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Create New" Command="{Binding AddNewTagCategoryCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedTagCategory}">
    <telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageAddSmall}" />
    </telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem.Icon>
</telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem>
<telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Manage">
    <telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Style="{StaticResource ImageEditSmall}"/>
    </telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem.Icon>
</telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem>
<telerikNavigation:RadSeparator />
```

Unfortunately it's overwriting my statically defined items ("Create New" and "Manage") with the ones off of the ItemsSource.  Is there some way to get both to place nice together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation, I found out that the RadMenu does not support the mixing of static and dynamic items at the same level.  The best workaround is to create a submenu to hold your dynamic items and link to it from your static items.